# Run the needle program for a query against the subject files and return the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, bioinformatics

I have written the script to run locally the [needle program](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/psa/emboss_needle/) for a query against the subject files. It returns the highest percentage result file as a string. In addition it also converts to html file (write_html function).

Can you help me to improve the script?

```
subject_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"subject_files/"
query_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+"query_file/"


def run_bug():
    """The script runs the needle program for a query file against all the subject files in a folder and keeps only
    the highest identity score alignments.
    """

    query_list_fastafiles, subject_list_fastafiles = start_function()
    files_ending_with_one = filter_files_ending_with_one(subject_list_fastafiles)

    for j in range(len(query_list_fastafiles)):
        initial = 0
        needle_alignment_result = ''

        #take the scaffold sequence one by one
        for i in range(len(files_ending_with_one)):

            #path of the files
            file1 = query_path+ordered_query_fastafiles[j]
            file1 = subject_path+files[i]
            needle_output = run_needle_two_sequences(file1, file2)

            if needle_output == None:
                return needle_alignment_result = needle_output
            else:
                #print(ordered_query_fastafiles[j],ordered_scaffold_fastafiles[i])
                identity_percentage, result_file_as_string = needle_output
                #print(identity_percentage, results)
                identity_percentage = float(identity_percentage)

                if identity_percentage > initial:
                #keeps the highest percentage result among the files
                    initial = identity_percentage
                    needle_alignment_result = result_file_as_string

    write_html(needle_alignment_result)
    return needle_alignment_result
```

Comment: Ah I see the comment on your answer- un-rolledback

Comment: `return needle_alignment_result = needle_output` is not valid Python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very short review, as I don't have the time for a more extensive one.

## Enumerate

Some things I see right off the bat is `range(len())`. Instead of writing this, consider using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). This will allow you to work with any iterable, not just countable, indexable objects.

## Unnecessary `else`

I see this piece of code next:

```
if needle_output == None:
    return needle_alignment_result = needle_output
else:
    ... code here ...
```

The `else` here is unnecessary, as you exit the function after returning in the `if`. Just move the code in the `else` right after the `if`, and remove the unnecessary `else`, like so:

```
if needle_output == None:
    return needle_alignment_result = needle_output
... code here ...
```

## `is None` vs `== None`

Below is from an amazing [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257957/8968906).

> A class is free to implement
>   comparison any way it chooses, and it
>   can choose to make comparison against
>   None means something (which actually
>   makes sense; if someone told you to
>   implement the None object from
>   scratch, how else would you get it to
>   compare True against itself?).

Practically-speaking, there is not much difference since custom comparison operators are rare.  But you should use `is None` as a general rule.

***Updated Code***

```
def run_bug():
    """
    The script runs the needle program for a query file against all the
    subject files in a folder and keeps only the highest identity score alignments.
    """
    needle_alignment_result = ''

    query_list_fastafiles, subject_list_fastafiles = start_function()
    files_ending_with_one = filter_files_ending_with_one(subject_list_fastafiles)

    for j, _ in enumerate(query_list_fastafiles):
        initial = 0

        # Take the scaffold sequence one by one
        for i, _ in enumerate(files_ending_with_one):

            # Path of the files
            file1 = query_path + ordered_query_fastafiles[j]
            file1 = subject_path + files[i]
            needle_output = run_needle_two_sequences(file1, file2)

            if needle_output is None:
                return needle_alignment_result == needle_output

            identity_percentage, result_file_as_string = needle_output
            identity_percentage = float(identity_percentage)

            # Keeps the highest percentage result among the files
            if identity_percentage > initial:
                initial = identity_percentage
                needle_alignment_result = result_file_as_string

    write_html(needle_alignment_result)
    return needle_alignment_result
```

Comment: `enumerate` is only called-for if you're using both the value and the index. In this case you only use the index, so the OP's solution is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a few reads to understand what's going on here, but I think I do, now. You're best to separate this into at least two parts: one part that generates the percentage and alignment result, and one part that applies the `max` function to get the best percentage-result tuple. This can be done easily with a function that `yields` whenever it gets such a tuple.

After some investigation in chat, we've arrived at a prior-to hidden business requirement: `query_list_fastafiles` will only ever be a sequence of length 1. As such, you definitely shouldn't have a loop. Instead, you should probably `assert len(query_list_fastafiles) == 1` and then continue on with the inner loop. Having an outer loop will simply discard all results for the inner loop except the last one.

Comment: Since each query file will have a needle alignment result. The case is (1) where this loop produce needle_alignment_result.

Comment: OK... but it doesn't do that. `needle_alignment_result` is overwritten in the inner loop.

Comment: You are right. The new needle_alignment_result should define inside the j loop. I did a mistake while copying. BTW: Just realized run_bug is a weird name. It has to be run_needle.

Comment: @catuf OK. Please edit your question to reflect your real code.

Comment: So, this is not an improvement. You're still running `needle_alignment_result = result_file_as_string` in the inner loop without a break. Think about the behaviour if the inner loop finds two results. Which should it take? Currently it will only take the last.

Comment: May be I am missing the point. How will inner loop have two results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98755/discussion-between-reinderien-and-catuf).